# How to make sense of my cat's whining and resolve it?

Tags: cats, vocalizations, communication

My cat (Grammer) is a 1.5 year old male rescue who is the most friendly and gentle cat I've ever had. I adopted him because my other kitten (Marduk) who is two months older was not properly socialized (removed from his mom and the litter too early) and he needed a buddy to solve some behavioral problems only another cat companion could solve.

Marduk is now super-chill, but Grammar is extremely vocal and whines/whimpers constantly. His vocalization isn't limited to needs/wants necessarily. He makes noises like trills while he's playing with toys or (whimpers, meows) while exploring heights and climbing, too. I initially bought him an iPad to play Game for Cats and his favorite: Mouse for Cats. This minimized his whimpering at first. Then he got bored with it. (By the way, he likes to play R&B on my Apple Music subscription...) So I bought him many other more tactile toys. All of them with similar effects initially but the same result over time. His whimpering can really drive me crazy -- especially while I'm heads down with my work and need to focus, distraction free.

I work from home and this constant vocalization is driving me absolutely insane. I love my little buddy, but what can I do beyond what I have done to quiet him down a little?

What's really cute is if I make eye contact he knows he got my attention and comes over... Oh, and he eats twice as much as Marduk, and is twice the size -- sideways. He has such a personality.

What can I do to minimize his vocalizations? I've done everything I can think of to make his life as interesting as possible. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Not an answer for the whining, but toy boredom may be solved by rotating toys every few days, rather than leaving them all out all the time.

Comment: He loves the latest toy I bought him, but he is burning through the batteries... Such a hard nut to crack

Comment: Your cats seem amazing! I don't have a full answer for cat vocalizations - some cats are just chirpy and chatty. Have you tried ignoring him while you're working? If you respond at all, even to shush or look at him, he knows that a chip or whine will result in attention.

Comment: @Gwendolyn, I just started doing this -- and while annoying seems to be working. I just feel bad because I wonder if I'm missing something he needs.

Comment: @Dshiz From your lovingly written paragraphs, I'm sure you care for them well. If the cat's behavior starts to change and/or the noises sound worrying, you can take them to the vet for a check-up. But in my cat experience, chatty cats just like chatting, and we're good listeners. :)